# linked list from java to c++

Tags: c++

here is code to implement linked list i hope you understand main purpose  of this code such kind of code is written in java  and i am trying to implement in  c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class link {
public:
    int idata;
    double ddata;
    link ( int id,double dd){
        idata=id;
        ddata=dd;
    }
public :
    void display(){

        cout<<idata<<"=>";
        cout<<ddata;

    }

}; link next;


class  linked_list{
public :
    link first;

public:
     linked_list(){

         first=NULL;
     }

public:
    bool isempthy(){
        return (first==NULL);
    }
    void insert(int  id,double dd){






link    newlink= link(id,dd);
newlink.next=first;
 first=newlink;

}








int main(){




     return 0;
}
```

but it has some bugs please help me  i  think it is possible to rewrite  written code in java in c++

Comment: I'd say i didn't understand your english. Then i'd say that linked_list interface is somewhat strange. It is not like java's LinkedList. So how can i try to find bugs if code doesn't do anything from it's task?

Comment: it is code from algorithms and data structure in java second edition
 and also about my english sorry i am not english man so  sorry:)

Comment: If you're learning C++, you'd be better off starting from the beginning with a good book than trying to transplant your knowledge of Java. They are quite different languages. In particular, you need to understand pointers and memory management to implement a linked list in C++ - these are the main errors in your code.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class link {
public:
    int idata;
    double ddata;
    link* next;

    link ( int id,double dd){
        idata=id;
        ddata=dd;
        next = NULL;
    }

    void display(){
        cout<<idata<<"=>";
        cout<<ddata;
    }
};


class  linked_list{
public :
    link* first;

    linked_list(){
        first = NULL;
    }

     ~linked_list(){
         while(first != NULL){
         link* ptr = first->next;
         delete first;
         first = ptr;
         }
     }

public:
    bool isempthy(){
        return (first == NULL);
    }

    void insert(int  id,double dd){
        link* newlink = new link(id,dd);
        newlink->next= first;
        first = newlink;
    }


int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pointers in C++ to create the connections between the list elements.

I suggest reading some single linked list [example](http://www.tutorialhero.com/click-30469-an_implementation_of_a_singly_linked_list_of_integers.php) (or [this](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Singly-linked_list)) in C++ before attempting to create your own implementation.