# full code from java in c++

Tags: c++

here is  full code  from algorithm and data structure in java  written in c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class link {
public:
    int idata;
    double ddata;
    link *next;
    link ( int id,double dd){
        idata=id;
        ddata=dd;
    }
public :
    void display(){

        cout<<idata<<"=>";
        cout<<ddata;

    }

}; 


class  linked_list{
public :
    link *first;

public:
     linked_list(){

         first=NULL;
     }
      ~linked_list(){

          while (first!=NULL){
              link *ptr=first->next;
              delete first;
              first=ptr;
          }

      }
public:
    bool isempthy(){
        return (first==NULL);
    }
    void insert(int  id,double dd){


link *newlink= new link(id,dd);
newlink->next=first;
 first=newlink;

}
public:
    link deletefirst(){

        link *temp=first;
        first=first->next;
        return *temp;

    }

    void displaylist(){
        cout<<"List (first-->last";

        link *current=first;

        while (current!=NULL){
            current->next;
            current.display();
        }



    }






}



int main(){

    linked_list ll;
    ll.insert(22,12);
    ll.insert(44,35);
    ll.insert(12,46);
    ll.insert(100,23.45);
    while (!ll.isempthy()){
        link alink=ll.deletefirst();

        alink.display();
    }


     return 0;
}
```

error is that this  fragment

```
current.display();  does not work  please help
```

Comment: If you're using C++, perhaps you should get a copy of [Algorithms and Data Structures in C++](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=R86nZ5b__I0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=algorithms+and+data+structures+in+C%2B%2B&source=bl&ots=JHb5a2wqAI&sig=PG4mAXXrxGmBQjTXwlb7GXVkvLQ&hl=en&ei=YpdJTOPEC5K6sQPIwJxI&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: this line 
current->next;
does nothing...

Comment: possible duplicate of [ linked list from java to c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318086/linked-list-from-java-to-c)

Comment: If you're going to use a linked list in C++, why not use `std::list`? That way, when you come to your senses, it'll be relatively easy to change to another data structure.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you get a compiler error? If so, then tell us exactly what the error message is. Or does it not do what you expected? If so, then what did you expect, and how is that different from what it really does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void displaylist(){
        cout<<"List (first-->last";

        link *current=first;

        while (current!=NULL)
        {
            //display the current node
            current->display();
           //then move to the next one
            current = current->next;
          }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

link *current
use current-> instead of current.